# Node.js with Redis - Sorted sets addition

Tags: node.js, redis

I'm trying to make a list of URLs using node_redis. In the code below I'm getting the length on the sorted set and adding elements to that position of the set.

```
client.on('connect', function() {       
    client.zcard('url',function(err, reply) {
        if (reply == undefined) {
            length = 0;
        } else {
            length = reply;
        }
    });
    client.zadd('url',length,pagename,function(err1, reply1) {
        console.log("added="+reply1);
    });             
    client.zrange('url',0,-1,'withscores',function(err2, reply2) {
        console.log(reply2);
    });
});
```

My issue is that `reply1` returns undefined which means that `length` is not assigned the length of the set by the previous piece of code. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: That would probably be because the call to `zcard` has yet to return when you call `zadd` - try moving `zadd`inside `zcard`'s callback (and then do the same for `zrange`)

Comment: You're calling code concurrently - and completion order is not guaranteed. But seems like what you want is sequential execution (first, then second, then third method). Use `async.waterfall` from `async` module, or just chain callback so each next function is executed in previous function callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include the action that needs to happen inside the reply of `ZCARD` this way you make sure that it happens once the callback has a reply for you. the example you have is falling into the case where JS is already checking for the length value without waiting for it to be instantiated by the ZCARD call

```
client.on('connect', function() {       
    client.zcard('url',function(err, reply) {
        if (reply == undefined) {
            length = 0;
        } else {
            length = reply;
        }

         client.zadd('url',length,pagename,function(err1, reply1) {
             console.log("added="+reply1);
         }); 

         client.zrange('url',0,-1,'withscores',function(err2, reply2) {
            console.log(reply2);
         });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NX (Not Exist) flag, and ZCOUNT.

```
ZCOUNT url -inf +inf 
ZADD url NX http://a.com
ZRANGE url 0 -1 WITHSCORES
```